# I need a console command to empty my inventory

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I am carrying way too much stuff in my inventory, and I need a way to drop it all with a console command like being able to take everything from a chest. I need to store everything in a chest in one fell swoop without manually doing it all.

Comment: There are a few sorting mods on the nexus that could probably easily do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the `removeallitems` command, targeting yourself?

Description:
Removes all items in the targets inventory. Use the 'player' variable to transfer all items to own inventory.

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)

Comment: This removes the items, not drops them

Comment: Thanks for this the command did what I needed but it was a little tricky to target myself

Comment: Does this work for spells, too?

Comment: To target yourself, you can also type player.removeallitems. Targeting yourself with the mouse is just a shortcut.